# Cannot independently set padding on TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout

While testing some designs for a LinearLayout for the elements in a ListView, I stumbled upon some weird behaviour. As you can see in the added code, I have three TextViews in a horizontal LinearLayout. I wanted to set the padding for one of these TextViews, but it seems that this value is also applied to the other TextViews as a margin of some sort (see pictures).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_list_row_symbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="O"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_list_row_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:text="oxygen"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_list_row_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="8"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Set `android:paddingTop="0dp"` on all TextViews
[image: padding_top_set_to_0]

Set `android:paddingTop="16dp"` only on first TextView
[image: padding_top_set_to_16]

Do any of you know why the padding cannot be set independently on one of these TextViews?

Comment: What happenes if set `android:marginTop="16dp"` only on first TextView?

Comment: You mean `android:layout_marginTop="16dp"`? That does seem to apply the margin to only the first TextView.

Comment: Yes, `android:layout_marginTop`. Is it what you want?

Comment: Not really, no. But I just bumped into this behaviour and I mainly wanted to know whether I did something wrong or if this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior seems correct as padding is applied to the content of a view - not to the view itself. However, the remaining child views following the padding from first child view seems erroneous.

As an alternate, I would suggest you to replace `paddingTop` with `layout_marginTop` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have given padding to only one text view. If you want all text view than you will have to keep all three within one LinearLayout and set property i.e setPadding() or setPaddingTop().

I think this might help you.